# The requested schema does not exist or not authorized

Tags: c#, .net, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using **Snowflake.Data.Client** dll in c#.Net to connect to Snowflake DB I have below code to connect to Snowflake and execute the query

```
_connectionstringname = _strProcessName + "connectionString";
_swfsqlconn = GetSnowFlakeConnection(_connectionstringname);

if (_query.Contains("{FromDate}") || _query.Contains("{ToDate}"))
{
    _query = _query.Replace("{FromDate}", _strFromDate)
                   .Replace("{ToDate}", _strToDate);
}

_swfsqlcmd.CommandText = _query;
_swfsqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

_swfsqlcmd.Connection = _swfsqlconn;

if (_swfsqlconn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    _swfsqlconn.Open();
}

SnowflakeDbDataAdapter oda = new SnowflakeDbDataAdapter(_swfsqlcmd);

oda.Fill(qrds);
```

When I try to open the connection I get the error

> Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbException: 'Error: The requested schema does not exist or is not authorized. SqlState: 08006, VendorCode: 390201, QueryId: '

The user I am using has been given all the permissions and I am able to connect and run the query in the DBeaver UI Interface, in .Net I face this error please help

Comment: Can you check  if the query is same when running from DBeaver UI and the  C# code are same, also check if the schema name is being passed in your C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this kind of error message is correct.
To debug, I would try two things:

1. In the code log _query, and see if it is the right one
2. Take the query id, and check it in Snowflake UI query history

Put attention that if the Schema name is quoted, it is case sensitive. So, either remove the quotes or have the same.
Check with Snowflake query history if the user is the same when you run from .NET and DBeaver.
Either specify the database name in the query or check that the default database is correct.